# PyMongo iterate through documents / arrays within documents, replace found values

Tags: python, arrays, pymongo

I have the following data in Mongodb:

```
{ "_id" : 1, "items" : [ "apple", "orange", "plum" ] }
{ "_id" : 2, "items" : [ "orange", "apple", "pineapple" ] }
{ "_id" : 3, "items" : [ "cherry", "carrot", "apple" ] }
{ "_id" : 4, "items" : [ "sprouts", "pear", "lettuce" ] }
```

I am trying to make a function using Python / PyMongo that takes 2 arguments, an old and a new string.  I would like to find  all the "apple" in all of the arrays across all of the documents and replace them with the string "banana".

Below is the code I have so far:

```
def update(old, new):
    for result in db.collection.find({"items" : old}):
        for i in result["items"]:
            if i == old:
                db.collection.update({"_id": result["._id"]}, {"$set": {"items": new}})
```

Comment: def update(old, new):
    for result in db.collection.find({"items" : old}):
        db.collection.update({ doc['_id'], items: old}, { $set: {"items.$" : new }})        #this does not work either

Answer (score 1):

Finally figured this out, it is actually really simple:

```
from pymongo import MongoClient

mongo_client = MongoClient(127.0.0.1, 27017)
db = mongo_client.my_databse

def update(old, new)
    for result in db.collection.find({'items' : old}):
        db.collection.update_one({ '_id': result['_id'], 'items': old}, { '$set' : {'items.$' : new}})
```

Answer (score 0):

use [update_many()](http://api.mongodb.com/python/current/api/pymongo/collection.html#pymongo.collection.Collection.update_many) to update multiple documents in one query instead of looping through the documents.
    from pymongo import MongoClient

```
mongo_client = MongoClient(127.0.0.1, 27017)
db = mongo_client.my_databse

def update(old, new)
     db.collection.update_many({'items': old}, { '$set' : {'items.$' : new}})
```

For pymongo less than ***3.2*** use update with multi flag

```
def update(old, new)
     db.collection.update({'items': old}, { '$set' : {'items.$' : new}}, multi=True)
```